# HTML doesn't show button if not in a local network using webiopi.js, how show it on the browser?

Tags: gpio, web-browsers, webiopi, javascript, html5

I followed a tutorial made by Jerry Hildenbrand, where he teaches how to control a LED via local network.

His tutorial works perfectly, I just need to type `tightvncserver` in the raspberry and open any browser (even in the mobile) with the raspberry pi ID address and everything works perfectly.

The problem is if I try to open the

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="viewport" content = "height = device-height, width = device-width, user-scalable = yes" /> 
        <title>Pi-lights</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/superled.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/superled.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="10x10" href="/img/LED-icon.png" />
</head>
<body>
        </br>
        </br>
        <div id="content" align="center"></div>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        <p align="center">Push button; turn the led on</p>
        </br>
        </br>
</body>
</html>
```

The button created in javascript doesn't appear in my browser(like in the browser on right side), even though I can make the background color appear just changing the CSS path (removing the slash)

from

```
<href="/css/superled.css">
```

to

```
<href="css/superled.css">
```

I don't know why, all the folders and files follow the same structures that is inside the raspberry pi).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing the same (removing the leading slash) with the 2 javascript paths?

Comment: Yes, I did. still not appearing.

Comment: When I am using the raspberry IP address the page is normal, just when I open the index.html there is the problem.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/347651): why are you trying to locally open the `index.html` file if requesting it from the RPi's web server works?

Comment: Because it is easier and faster for edit and test any new alteration a make in the code. Also I am new using html, javascript and raspberry pi, so I am not sure what is the best way to program.  Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you open your website from web server http://192.168.0.38:8000 all resources images or js files are relative or absolute to the root web site folder for example `<href="/css/superled.css">` mean for the browser the file located in : `/Users/.../myhomefolder/mywebsitefolder/css/superled.css`, but when you open the file from file system `File://Users/.../index.html` resources are relative to the root system folder which mean the browser will search file in the current path : `/css/superled.css` which for sure is not correct. instead opening file from File system open the web server page.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was expecting. Thank you very much. You very good.

Comment: @ThiagoFarias Please accept the answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.